Getting the width of a group node
I know we can change the node width in Blender 4.3 but how can we find out what a group node width is when we stretch it out (It says 140 but that's just the default not the current changed width of the selected group node)?  See image below.


Select the node (so it is active), ⬆ ShiftF4, then paste into the console:
C.area.type='NODE_EDITOR';C.area.ui_type='GeometryNodeTree';C.window_manager.clipboard=str(C.active_node.width)

↩ Enter and now you have the width in your clipboard.

Thanks, looks like they may want to add a simple info box that shows this

@Still You can try to request that, but I don't know if there is a huge demand for that. After all the important thing is what the nodes produce, not which size they have in the editor. Anyway, a place for feature requests like this might be here: Right-Click Select Blender Community

@GordonBrinkmann I wrote one feature request on the right-click select, and it displayed the post as published, but it was visible to only me (dark ux pattern), and it was never published to anyone else, and without any response why. So I can't recommend this site.

@MarkusvonBroady I never requested any feature, I only know that others have suggested it before on other questions, and since I never needed something like that I have no other recommendations unfortunately.
